# Check if ListView item selected

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I wanna make my Button's IsEnabled property to check if ListView has a selection.
Is there any way to check if any ListView item is selected using only XAML?
Something like:

```
<Button Content="Remove" Command="{Binding RemoveConditionCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=conditionsListView, Path=SelectedItem}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=conditionsListView, Path=IsSelected}"
                />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using **`DataTrigger`**. Set IsEnabled to false in case selectedItem is null for ListView.

Sample:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,
                                               ElementName=conditionsListView}"
                             Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```